# Prevent tomcat from crashing at every java update

Tags: java, html, tomcat, tomcat8, rhel7

me and my team have a machine (CentOs/RHEL7) running a webapp with tomcat 8 as a service.

What we experience is that at every single automatic java update, the tomcat service tries to restart and it can't do that due to the path set statically into the startup script.

Is there a way to set it automatically at every update?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to disable the automatic updates on your server and define a schedule to install all your available updates.